# How to calculate customer acquisition rate by finding out overlapping with previous years?

Tags: r, overlapping

I have a date set `CustOrder`about customer purchases from 2008-2013 with following information (this just part of the data):

```
CustID  OrderYear  Amount
101102  2008       22429.00
101102  2009       11045.00
101435  2010       10740.77
101435  2011       73669.50
107236  2012       162123.50
101416  2010       8102.00
101416  2011       360.00
101416  2012       36576.00
101416  2013       1960.00
101467  2012       997.00
101604  2010       2971.53
101664  2009       91.94
101664  2011       130.93
.........
```

Some customers may purchases continuously every year (i.e. 101416), or just certain years (i.e. 101664). I want to figure out the customer acquisition rate, that is how many new customers gained that year, in terms of rate and numbers (For customers who did not purchase continuously, only consider the first time of purchase).  For instance,

```
Year Customer  TotalCustomerNumber NewCustomerRate
2008   5          5                     0%
2009   3          8                     37%
2010   4          12                    33%
2011   2          14                    14%
2012   3          17                    17%
2013   2          19                    10%
```

Anyone have any ideas/hints how to do it?

I appreciate any helps!

Comment: subset the year; use unique on the customer id, then count the No of occurrences of the unique IDs.

Comment: I believe you would have create a loop to loop through each year and calculate the new customer acquisition that year. Using the current year in the loop you can subset the data inside the loop for only IDs less than that year, `df[df$Year < currentYear, "ID"]` and find which IDs in that subset are NOT in your current year and consider those IDs to be new users and go from there, looping through each year as you build your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time to work out a solution and this method should work. Take a look a the comments for details:

```
# Setting a seed for reproducibility.
set.seed(10)

# Setting what years we want allowed.
validYears <- 2008:2015

# Generating a "fake" dataset for testing purposes.
custDF <- data.frame(CustID = abs(as.integer(rnorm(250, 50, 50))), OrderYear = 0, Amount = abs(rnorm(250, 100, 1000)))
custDF$OrderYear <- sapply(custDF$OrderYear, function(x) x <- sample(validYears, 1)) # Adding random years for each purchase.

# Initializing a new data frame to store the output values.
newDF <- data.frame(Year = validYears, NewCustomers = 0, RunningNewCustomerTotal = 0, NewCustomerRate = "")
custTotal <- 0 # Initializing a variable to be used in the loop.
firstIt <- 1 # Denotes the first iteration.

for (year in validYears) { # For each uniqueYear in your data set (which I arbitarily defined before making the dataset)

  # Getting the unique IDs of the current year and the unique IDs of all past years.
  currentIDs <- unique(custDF[custDF$OrderYear == year, "CustID"])
  pastIDs <- unique(custDF[custDF$OrderYear < year, "CustID"])

  if (firstIt == 1) { pastIDs <- c(-1) } # Setting a condition for the first iteration.

  newIDs <- currentIDs[!(currentIDs %in% pastIDs)] # Getting all IDs that have not been previously used.
  numNewIDs <- length(newIDs) # Getting the number of new IDs.
  custTotal <- custTotal + numNewIDs # Getting the running total.

  # Adding the new data into the data frame.
  newDF[newDF$Year == year, "NewCustomers"] <- numNewIDs
  newDF[newDF$Year == year, "RunningNewCustomerTotal"] <- custTotal

  # Getting the rate.
  if (firstIt == 1) { 

    NewCustRate <- 0
    firstIt <- 2

  } else { NewCustRate <- (1 - (newDF[newDF$Year == (year - 1), "RunningNewCustomerTotal"] / custTotal)) * 100 }

  # Inputting the new data. Format and round are just getting the decimals down.
  newDF[newDF$Year == year, "NewCustomerRate"] <- paste0(format(round(NewCustRate, 2)), "%")

}
```

With output:

```
> newDF
  Year NewCustomers RunningNewCustomerTotal NewCustomerRate
1 2008           32                      32              0%
2 2009           22                      54             41%
3 2010           19                      73             26%
4 2011           14                      87             16%
5 2012            7                      94            7.4%
6 2013            3                      97            3.1%
7 2014            9                     106            8.5%
8 2015            5                     111            4.5%
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Giraffe! It helps me a lot!!!I only changed a little thing `newDF <- data.frame(Year = validYears, NewCustomers = 0, RunningNewCustomerTotal = 0, NewCustomerRate = 0)` otherwise, I got error message  `invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: No worries. I just initialized that column to character class because I knew I'd have to concatenate it with "%" later, but whatever works.